# How to disable a global style when within an element

Tags: html, css

We are currently using Tailwin custom CSS found here https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/pull/116 the purpose of this css is to easily add borders to elements by just setting border width property, we can change the default border-style for all elements to solid and use border width to hide them

```
*,
 *::before,
 *::after {
   border-width: 0;
   border-style: solid;
   border-color: transparent;
 }
```

This bit of css is used system wide unfortunately I'm unable to remove it. Is there a way to prevent this css to apply to a certain class or ID?

For example if the element has a class disableTailwind, it should ignore that css block.

Any tips or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't you just include the same rules in a css file after the original on each page ?

```css
*,
 *::before,
 *::after {
   border-width: 1px;
   border-style: solid;
   border-color: black;
 }
 
 
 
 *,
 *::before,
 *::after {
   border-width: unset;
   border-style: unset;
   border-color: unset;
 }
```

```html
<div>test</div>
```

Comment: The problem with this, the same page may have elements that do use it and also don't need to use it. My application is very dynamic. Pages may or may not. I need to make it so none of these styles appear to a certain element and and child elements within it

Comment: You can override css of inner elements. This rule is very early in the css chain.

Answer (score 0):

Add `border:0;` or `border:none;` to that class or id.

Answer (score 0):

> For example if the element has a class disableTailwind, it should ignore that css block.

So, that's the use case for the `:not(...)` pseudo class, though to make it work, I had to put `body` before `*` selectors:

```css
body *:not(.disableTailwind),
body *:not(.disableTailwind)::before,
body *:not(.disableTailwind)::after {
   border-width: 3px;
   border-style: solid;
   border-color: red;
 }
```

```html
<body>
 <div>Without .disableTailwind</div>
 <div class="disableTailwind">With .disableTailwind</div>
 <br />
 <button>Without .disableTailwind</button>
 <button class="disableTailwind">With .disableTailwind</button>
</body>
```

Comment: great suggestion. May I ask if you have any ideas how to tweak it so any child elements where parent has disableTailWind would also be disabled?